# vala genie freeing memory

Tags: glib, gnome, vala, genie

My understanding is that Vala and Genie have reference counting rather than garbage collection.

Per Valadoc.org, this:

```
string path = Path.build_filename ("my", "full", "path/to.txt");
```

yields this:

```
a newly-allocated string that must be freed with g_free
```

Is this correct or is `g_free` not required due to reference counting?

If `string` is wrapped within an object will `g_free` on `string` be actioned on object destruction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valadoc contains the documentation from the original GLib, GObject, Gtk+, etc. libraries. It also contains additional Vala specific documentation on top of that.

You often see sentences which only makes sense in the context of the C programming language.

The Vala compiler does the memory management for you (most of the time). In this example a Vala `string` is actually translated by the Vala compiler to a `gchar *` in C where it has to be deallocated using `g_free` which the Vala compiler also does for you.

As a matter of fact strings are a bit different than objects as they are not reference counted, but copied instead.

Take this example in Vala:

```
int main () {
  Object obj1 = new Object ();
  Object obj2 = obj1;

  string s1 = "";
  string s2 = s1;
  return 0;
}
```

The (manually cleaned up) code that valac produces in C looks like this:

```
int main (void) {
    GObject* obj1 = g_object_new (G_TYPE_OBJECT, NULL);
    GObject* obj2 = g_object_ref (obj1);
    gchar* s1 = g_strdup ("");
    gchar* s2 = g_strdup (s1);
    g_free (s2);
    g_free (s1);
    g_object_unref (obj2);
    g_object_unref (obj1);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see `obj2` is a reference to the same object as in `obj1` and the object is only destroyed when both references are `unref`ed.

The string `s2` on the other side is a copy of the string stored in `s1` (which is in turn a copy of the string literal `""`).

As you can also see the compiler does take care of such details for you. It makes the manual reference counting and manual string copying automatic.

Comment: Excellent.  Yes it appears that Gtk/Vala/Genie are evolving so quickly that the Valadocs may not be current.  So, for the most part, only objects marked `unowned` require manual destruction, is that correct?

Comment: Only pointers require manual destruction. An object is automatically deleted when all of its owning references go out of scope. There are also some special objects in order to support non-GObject classes (compact classes). I would suggest you read this article about reference handling: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ReferenceHandling

Comment: There are also some details described here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/LegacyBindings#Using_Vala.27s_Automatic_Memory_Management

Comment: Note that ARC (automatic reference counting) is not a panacea. You still have issues like reference cycles (which have to be manually broken with `weak` references) and dangling references (unowned references that still point to an object which has been destructed).

Comment: Due to the various ways to use pointers in C APIs it is also crucially important that the `.vapi` files be correct in order for all this to work between languages.